# Does esbuild provide a feature like the resolve.alias option in webpack?

Tags: esbuild

Does esbuild provide a feature like the resolve.alias option in webpack?

```js
const path = require('path');
    
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
      Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/'),
    },
  },
};
```

Now, instead of using relative paths when importing like so:

```js
import Utility from '../../utilities/utility';
```

you can use the alias:

```js
import Utility from 'Utilities/utility';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to make sure that the `bundle` option is enabled.

If you're using JavaScript, create jsconfig.json file, and if you're using TypeScript, create a tsconfig.json file.

and use the `"paths"` compiler option as bellow for example:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler", // << you should enable this
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"] // << enable this (or your own)
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**/*"]
}
```

Then, when running esbuild, make sure to add the `--bundle` flag:

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "build": "esbuild --bundle ./index.ts # or for js, index.js"
}
```

```
$ npm run build
```

This will resolve imports like this:

```
import log from '@/tools'
```

To:

```
import log from '../../../tools'
```

Please note that this is only supported if you're using the `--bundle` flag, otherwise it will not resolve any alias and it will not show you any warning or an error during build.

If you're only writing code for the back-end, and you're for example not going to bundle your code, because simply you don't care, then, a better solution to you would be using an external plugin, or a third-party npm package for that, such as [ts-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) which is pretty cool & easy to use.

If you're doing that for the front-end and you're not using other bundler like webpack or swc, and your main purpose of using esbuild is to bundle your code, then congratulations you're ready to go.

Answer (score 5):

esbuild does currently not offer a dedicated way to resolve aliases but does support `paths` in `tsconfig.json`.
https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2191

Answer (score 4):

esbuild have no similar option in build options but it provides hancy way to control paths resolving via plugins. You can either write [simple own plugin](https://esbuild.github.io/plugins/#resolve) or use existing one such as [esbuild-plugin-alias](https://github.com/igoradamenko/esbuild-plugin-alias)

Comment: Actually the `paths` in `tsconfig.json` are supported with using a plugin

Comment: that `esbulid-plugin-alias` link gives me a 404